# How to make async call inside a sync operation in locust for WebSocket Testing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, gevent, locust

This is my WebSocket library similar to https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/locust_plugins/users/socketio.py

```
class WebsocketClient:
abstract = True
message_regex = re.compile(r"(\d*)(.*)")
description_regex = re.compile(r"<([0-9]+)>$")

def connect(self, endpoint, header={}):
    self.ws = websocket.create_connection(endpoint, header=header)
    Logger.log_message('Connection Established successfully')
    Logger.log_message('status code: {}'.format(self.ws.getstatus()))
    gevent.spawn(self.receive())
    Logger.log_message('spawning started....')

def receive(self):
    while True:
        message = self.ws.recv()
        Logger.log_message('WSR Original message: {}'.format(message))
        self.on_message(message)

def receive_1(self, ):
    message = self.ws.recv()
    Logger.log_message('WSR Original message: {}'.format(message))
    self.on_message(message)

def on_message(self, message):  # override this method in your subclass for custom handling
    m = self.message_regex.match(message)
    # response_time = 0  # unknown
    time_stamp = 0
    if m is None:
        # uh oh...
        raise Exception(f"got no matches for {self.message_regex} in {message}")
    code = m.group(1)
    json_string = m.group(2)
    if code == "0":
        event_type = 'open'
        current_timestamp = time.time()
        json_obj = json.loads(json_string)
        Logger.log_message('WSR: {}'.format(json_obj))
        Logger.log_message('time_stamp: {}'.format(current_timestamp))
        name = '{} | {}'.format(code, event_type)
        time_stamp = current_timestamp
    elif code == "2":
        name = "2 | heartbeat"
    elif code == "40" or code == "42":
        current_timestamp = time.time()
        json_obj = json.loads(json_string)
        Logger.log_message('WSR: {}'.format(json_obj))
        Logger.log_message('time_stamp: {}'.format(current_timestamp))
        event_type = json_obj[0]
        name = '{} | {}'.format(code, event_type)
        time_stamp = current_timestamp
    else:
        print("Received unexpected message: {}".format(message))
        Logger.log_message("Received unexpected message: {}".format(message), LogType.ERROR)
        return
    events.request.fire(
        request_type="WSR",
        name=name,
        response_time=None,
        response_length=len(message),
        context=None,
        exception=None
    )

def send(self, body):
    start_at = time.time()
    if body == "2" or body == "3":
        name = "{} heartbeat".format(body)
    else:
        # hoping this is a subscribe type message, try to detect name
        m = re.search(r'(\d*)\["([a-z]*)"', body)
        Logger.log_message(m)
        code = m.group(1)
        event_type = m.group(2)
        name = '{} | {}'.format(code, event_type)
    Logger.log_message("WSS - payload: {}".format(body))
    self.ws.send(body)
    events.request.fire(
        request_type="WSS",
        name=name,
        response_time=int((time.time() - start_at) * 1000000),
        response_length=len(body),
        context=None,
        exception=None
    )

def sleep_with_heartbeat(self, seconds):
    while seconds >= 0:
        gevent.sleep(min(15, seconds))
        seconds -= 15
        self.send('3')

def close(self):
    self.ws.close()
```

class CustomWebsocketLocust(User):
abstract = True

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomWebsocketLocust, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.client = WebsocketClient()
```

My Test code is like this:

[image]

But when I am running this locust file, it is getting stuck in the first task and the second task is never executed.

I thought gevent.spawn() would create an async thread that will keep continuously listening to all events and other sync calls will happen simultaneously by the locust thread. But it is not happening as expected

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: dont add your code as a screenshot, reduce your issue to as few lines of code as you can. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I vaguely remember something about gevent job not releasing lock unless there is a sleep around somewhere. Can you try adding gevent.sleep(0) in receive method? I am not sure if it would work though. And can I ask why don't you close the ws instead of quitting the runner?